# unable to stat srcFile error for grunt:compress

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compress

I am getting

> Warning: unable to stat srcFile (folderName) Use --force to continue.

When i am running grunt:compress

```
compress: {
    main: {
        options: {
          archive: function () {
            return  "build/build"+ '.zip'
          }
        },

        files: [
          {
            cwd:"/log/path/to/folder/where/apk/is/kept/",
            src: ["**/*"],
            dest: 'android'
          }

          ]


}}
```

This works fine if I dont mention dest and only src(full path till **/*) but in that case i get the zip with all folders of path present.
Any help ??

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a similar problem by using the following config.

```
compress: {
  main: {
    options: {
      archive: "portlet-coverage.war" ,
      mode: 'zip'
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, 
       dot: true, 
       cwd: '../../target', 
       src: '**/*' 
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

more information is available at http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

Comment: expand:true is the key.